# Backbone.js and jQuery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js

I'm trying to create a jQuery UI accordion widget out of markup rendered by a Backbone.js view. My view code is as follows:

```
var AccessPointAccordion = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("#access_point_accordion"),
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new AccessPoint(bootstrappedModels);
    this.render();  // renders the markup correctly
    this.$el.accordion();
  }
  .
  .
  .
});
```

While the markup is being rendered correctly, it is not being rendered as an accordion widget, instead just being left as unstyled markup. I'm a Backbone.js newbie, can someone point out if I'm making a simple mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: Probably a markup problem, it seems to work as is http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/wYSZF/ Could you show your template and rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this inside your render function:

```
render: function(){

    //template and other code

    setTimeout("this.$el.accordion();",0);

    return this;
}
```

Comment: I'm more looking for an explanation as to why my approach doesn't work as opposed to a quick-fix/hack, but I will try that and see if it works for now.

Comment: Well it's due to the async nature of Javascript. Even you are calling accordion() after render() you are not guaranteed that the render function has finished and thus the rendered element are present in the DOM. So you have to find a way to be sure that the elements are inside the DOM when you call accordion(). SetTimeout is useful because it should wait until the browser has control again to call the function. Personally I use Backbone Marionette which has useful custom events that fire after or before the view has been rendered [Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs)